# How to link my primary key to to another table as a foreign key?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am making a small project with a DB of a "book_store". I am planning to have a two tables :

Books -> table(It consists of `id` as a Primary Key, and `genre_id` as a Foreign_key of genre).
Genre table will have multiple genres(comedy, horror with its unique id)
Genre -> table(id as a Primary Key, and yes this column will link to `Books` table as a primary Key)
Here is the implementation of `Book table`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String author;

    @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", unique = true)
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Genre genre;
```

And here is my `Genres`  table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "genres")
public class Genre {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "genre_id")
    private int id;
    private String genre;
```

So result of `Book` table i am getting is like this:
[I am using PostgresQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5ms7.png)

and table of `Genre`
[Genre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAb1R.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAb1R.png)

So my question is like this , while i am adding a new book ,and putting a genre 2 -> that means comedy, the `Error is occured , that is telling that repeating of Unique key  genres_pkey`?
Thanks for feedback!

Comment: `OneToOne`? You mean every genre is tied to one single book? Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One to one means that a Book has a single genre and that a single genre can only be used for a book. You have also specified `unique=true`, meaning that in the column `genre_id` you cannot have the same id twice.

Your description is not clear but I'm assuming multiple books can have the same genre.

The mapping in this case changes to a many-to-one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String author;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id")
    private Genre genre;
}
```

It also seems weird there books cannot have multiple genres (what about horror comedy stories?). In that case you will need [a bidirectional one-to-many](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many).

Comment: Anyway while i want to add a book , and type genre_id as 2 `comedy` , exception occured saying that genres_pkey is unique , so that i already have 2 in my table genres

Comment: but i just want to link my book table to genre , so that books can be shown by its genre

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: yeap i tried , i added a new book , but then i put id 2 to show thtat it is comedy , it gave me exception , and wrote that pk_genre is already exists

Comment: How do you assign the genre? Can you show the code that creates the book and assign the genre?

Comment: How do you load the Genre? I think the Cascade.ALL it's trying to persist it when you create the book. This could happen if the genre is not managed when you create the book. I cannot say for sure without looking at the code

Comment: Here is the Book model
 ```@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String author;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id")
    private Genre genre;
```
And this is the Genre model->```@Entity
@Table(name = "genres")
public class Genre {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "genre_id")
    private int id;
    private String genre;
```

Comment: I don't need the model, I need to know how you create a Book. You should have something like: `Book book = new Book(); ... book.setGenre(em.getReference(Genre.class, 5L)); em.persist(book);`

Comment: oh, cause i made a Restfult Service , i am just sending in Json format like this,
i am sending a POST method with swagger or Postman just to test my endPoint Controller 
```
{
  "author": "Harry Potter",
  "genre": {
    "id": 2
  },
  "name": "Comedy book"
}
```
@PostMapping(value = "/createBooks") 
public void createBook(     @RequestBody Book book )
```

Comment: I suspect that's the issue. When the new Genre object is created, Hibernate see it as a completely new element and try to persist it.

Comment: Try removing `CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: it is still same, i have checked why , but anyway didnot find any reasons

Comment: No idea then, if you create a testcase I can run somewhere, I will have look

Comment: you mean this test case?

```
  @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Book product = new Book("Morgan","Friemann",new Genre(2));
        mapper.writeValue(new File("person.json"), product);
        String jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(product);

Comment: `        mockMvc.perform(post("/createBooks")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(new Gson().toJson(product)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

Comment: Can you push the code somewhere? Like GitHub?

Comment: I am so sorry, Davide D'Alto, your advice worked, . How it worked i just put 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
then
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
After this manipulation it Worked , i am sorry for disturbing you, Thanks !!! you are the best!!!

Comment: I could not upvote your answer cause my reputation is less than 15, but i put a mark there , thank you so much1